Should I ask permission from my former PI after finishing my contract when I'm sole author of the paper?
I'm a postdoc and I worked with a PI with whom I had many issues and disagreement. I even went to HR to report him for breaking the law. He told me to write the paper by myself as a single author. Even before that, his presence wasn't helping. He was giving me zero feedback and deliberately wasn't helping me. He wasn't like that before. My contract had finally ended and I'm still working on the paper. I would like to know what are postdoc rights on the project after finishing the contract with the PI. I would like to have a collaborator, someone who can proofread the paper and give me suggestions. Is it OK to ask other people to collaborate with me without his permission, now that I'm not employed by him anymore? I asked ombudsperson in my university and he didn't reply my email. What is norm in academia in this situation?

From what you say, you already have his "permission" to publish as a sole author or otherwise exclude him. From what you say, you are ethically the sole author of the paper in its current state. I see no reason to ask (See caveat at the end).
If you want collaboration, however, the question is a bit more complex. Would a collaborator have enough intellectual input to the result to be considered an author? If so, it would seem to imply that more needs to be done and that there are unfilled holes in the current product.
One possibility for you to consider is to try to publish what you have, and then seek collaboration on extensions with one or more people who express interest in the work as published. If it has value, you will likely see some interest.
In some fields like CS where the typical publishing venue is a conference, the conference itself is a good place to meet interested people.
A complicating factor, of course, would be any contract you have signed with your PI that extends into the future.

In my opinion it is best to confirm, especially if all you have is a verbal agreement, I would get it on the record via email (if you already have that, then that is fine).
Further to that, you may also want to confirm that you have given appropriate credit to associated funding (this may go beyond your salary to centers or facilities which may have been involved) which is relevant to the work being published.
As to your needing a co-author or collaborator, that is entirely up to you, only you know the state of your work and the limitations of your knowledge.
